# Deleting KXStudio

Tags: system-installation

[image]I have KXStudio ( 31,59 GiB , Ubuntu studio Ubuntu 18.04 ( 93,39 GiB) and Ubuntu 18.04 ( 105,62 GiB ) installed on sda disk as shown on attached picture. I would  would like to keep only Ubuntu Studio and to delete other tw. How to do it safely? Please give procedure step-by-step . How to do it?